# How do I evaluate the expiration date on a ClaimsPrincipal?

Tags: c#, .net, claims-based-identity

I'm trying to read the expiration date on a ClaimsPrincipal in a .NET server application.

I think I understand how to obtain it:

```
Claim exp = accessClaimsPrincipal.FindFirst("exp");
```

This gives me a Claim object. I can get the .Value of the Claim object, which gives me a string. However, what I need is a DateTime object. How do I convert this Claim to a DateTime?

Answer (score 2):

The `exp` claim is in seconds since 1970, not ticks. Ref: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7519#section-2 -> `NumericDate`

So to parse that, use:

```
var exp = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(long.Parse(accessClaimsPrincipal.FindFirst("exp").Value));
//or as DateTime:
DateTime result = exp.UtcDateTime;
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [rfc7519](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7519#section-4.1.4) is should be a numeric date value (aka ticks). e.g. 637553398040000000

> The "exp" (expiration time) claim identifies the expiration time on
> or after which the JWT MUST NOT be accepted for processing.  The
> processing of the "exp" claim requires that the current date/time
> MUST be before the expiration date/time listed in the "exp" claim.
>
> Implementers MAY provide for some small leeway, usually no more than
> a few minutes, to account for clock skew.  Its value MUST be a number
> containing a NumericDate value.  Use of this claim is OPTIONAL.

So it needs a parse to `long` before converting to a `DateTime`

```
Claim exp = accessClaimsPrincipal.FindFirst("exp");
var expDate = new DateTime(long.Parse(exp.Value));
```

Comment: Alternative: if the string value has a timezone (or you know the timezone), use DateTimeOffset.

Comment: @gunr2171 it's worth noting, but probably not relevant to the answer.  Also, I wouldn't recommend `DateTimeOffset` unless you were actual handling an offset... If I were to raise concern or awareness on this matter, I was just draw attention to `DateTimeKind` [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.kind?view=net-5.0) - handling Unspecified, UTC or Local as it relates to parsing.

Comment: actually, I take that back.. according to [Choosing Between Datetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/choosing-between-datetime) the default should be `DateTimeOffset` for application development - this does also seem to be a good scenario for it, as you wouldn't otherwise accept ambiguity here.  So I agree, this answer could probably be improved with referencing of and to `DateTimeOffset` type as opposed to `DateTime`.  Sorry for the verbose commentary.